# Problem with serial port speed changing on BR300 or lower in c++ on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: c, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, baud-rate

I have to operate on serial port with baud rate equal BR300. However the commands   `cfsetspeed (&RSopt, (speed_t)B300);` and `tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &RSopt);` do not change the speed. As I've verified those commands work correctly for speeds B0 and higher than B300.

How can I set serial port transsmision speed to B300.

See my code bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main ()
{
    struct termios RSopt;
    int fd;

    fd = open( "/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY );    

    tcgetattr(fd, &RSopt);
    cfmakeraw(&RSopt);

    printf("Current speed:  ");
    printf("%d\n",RSopt.c_ispeed);
    printf("Change speed to 7 (B300)\n");
    cfsetspeed (&RSopt, (speed_t)B300);
    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &RSopt); 

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    tcgetattr(fd, &RSopt);
    printf("Current speed:  ");
    printf("%d",RSopt.c_ispeed);
    printf("  <--- speed not changed!\n");
    printf("Change speed to 9 (B1200)\n");
    cfsetspeed (&RSopt, (speed_t)B1200);
    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &RSopt);     

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    tcgetattr(fd, &RSopt);
    printf("Current speed:  ");
    printf("%d\n",RSopt.c_ispeed);
    printf("Change speed to 8 (B600)\n");
    cfsetspeed (&RSopt, (speed_t)B600);
    tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &RSopt);     

    tcgetattr(fd, &RSopt);
    printf("Current spped:  ");
    printf("%d\n",RSopt.c_ispeed);      
    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using **cfsetispeed()** and **cfsetospeed()** instead?

Comment: Also, try initializing your arguments before you give them to a function, like:   **speed_t my_speed = B300;**    
**cfsetspeed (&RSopt, my_speed);**

Comment: I have tried both ideas, but I did not succeed.

Comment: What do `cfsetspeed (&RSopt, (speed_t)B300);` and subsequent `tcsetattr (fd, TCSANOW, &RSopt);` return? What does `perror` say?

Comment: Both functions return 0. There is no error.

Comment: I've checked that, the problem occures also during setting the serial port parameters in command line: 

`stty -F /dev/ttyS0 speed 600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb` - OK; 

`stty -F /dev/ttyS0 speed 300 cs8 -cstopb -parenb` - error.